# How to inject a bean into custom argument resolver?

Tags: dependency-injection, spring-boot, autowired

Hello i use spring boot 1.3.2 version. I have a custom argument resolver which's name is `ActiveCustomerArgumentResolver`. Everything is great, `resolveArgument` method works fine but i can't initialize my service component which is of my custom arg. resolver. Is there a problem with lifecycle process? Here is my code:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
//other import statements

public class ActiveCustomerArgumentResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

@Autowired
private CustomerService customerService;

@Override
public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
    if (parameter.hasParameterAnnotation(ActiveCustomer.class) && parameter.getParameterType().equals(Customer.class))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

@Override
public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer, NativeWebRequest webRequest, WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {
    Principal userPrincipal = webRequest.getUserPrincipal();
    if (userPrincipal != null) {
        Long customerId = Long.parseLong(userPrincipal.getName()); 
        return customerService.getCustomerById(customerId).orNull(); //customerService is still NULL here, it keeps me getting NullPointerEx.
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No user principal is associated with the current request, yet parameter is annotated with @ActiveUser");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 10):

Let the Spring create the resolver for you by making it a `Component`:

```
@Component
public class ActiveCustomerArgumentResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {...}
```

Then inject the resolver into your `WebConfig` instead of simply using the `new`, like following:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired private ActiveCustomerArgumentResolver activeCustomerArgumentResolver;

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        argumentResolvers.add(activeCustomerArgumentResolver);
    }
}
```

Comment: This didn't work out but gave me a clue about the solution, i am adding it.

Comment: I'm not sure why it didn't work for you... this (or something very close to it) totally solved my problem.

Comment: In my case it doesn't work, at least in tests, because the addArgumentResolvers method gets called first, and then the mocking/autowiring takes place afterwards. So I also have to resort to something similar to @C.Köse below for testing at least.

Answer (score 1):

This is how i've solved the problem, not a generic one but helps me a lot:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        argumentResolvers.add(activeCustomerArgumentResolver());
    }

    @Bean
    public ActiveCustomerArgumentResolver activeCustomerArgumentResolver() {
        return new ActiveCustomerArgumentResolver();
    }
}
```